# Read QR Code in Unity with ARKit and ZXing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zxing, arkit

I'm trying to read a QR code with the following libraries:

- ARKit
- ZXing

However it doesn't seem to go well. After several hours I still don't manage to read out a decent QR code.
When debugging i apply the texture to see my result. It looks red because of the Texture Y but other than that it shows the QR code.
Interpreting the texture doesn't return any data analyzed by ZXing.

This is the following code i'm using for this:

```
#if UNITY_IOS && !UNITY_EDITOR
    // Update is called once per frame
    // BETTER: InvokeRepeating
    void Update()
    {
        if (!done) {
            ARTextureHandles handles = arSession.GetARVideoTextureHandles();
            //ARTextureHandles handles = UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface().GetARVideoTextureHandles();
            if (handles.IsNull())
            {
                return;
            }
            if (handles.TextureY != System.IntPtr.Zero) {
                ReadQRCode (handles.TextureY);
            }
        }

}
#endif

private void ReadQRCode(System.IntPtr mtlTexPtr)
{
    Debug.Log("---------------");
    Debug.Log("Scanning...");

    Resolution currentResolution = Screen.currentResolution;

    tex = (UnityEngine.Texture2D)GameObject.Find("Camera").GetComponent<UnityARVideo>().m_ClearMaterial.GetTexture("_textureCbCr");

    tex.UpdateExternalTexture(mtlTexPtr);

    try
    {
        if(barCodeReader == null) {
            Debug.Log("Could not find barcorereader");
        }
        if(tex == null) {
            Debug.Log("Could not find texture");
        }

        var data = barCodeReader.Decode(tex.GetPixels32(), currentResolution.width, currentResolution.height);
        if (data != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("QR: " + data.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("NO QR: " + "No QR code detected !");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error reading QR");
        Debug.LogError(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at Easy ML Kit which offers AR Foundation camera as one of the input sources - https://u3d.as/2PMe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further digging i came across an example that had something similar for OpenCV.

This proven to work for me with a good speed.

```
public class FrameCapturer : MonoBehaviour {

    // Script Inputs
    public bool m_shouldCaptureOnNextFrame = false;
    public Color32[] m_lastCapturedColors;

    // Privates
    Texture2D m_centerPixTex;

    void Start()
    {
        Resolution currentResolution = Screen.currentResolution;
        m_centerPixTex = new Texture2D(currentResolution.width, currentResolution.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
    }

    void OnPostRender()
    {

        if (m_shouldCaptureOnNextFrame)
        {
            Resolution res = Screen.currentResolution;
            m_lastCapturedColors = GetRenderedColors();
            m_shouldCaptureOnNextFrame = false;
        }
    }

    // Helpers
    Color32[] GetRenderedColors()
    {
        Resolution currentResolution = Screen.currentResolution;
        m_centerPixTex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, currentResolution.width, currentResolution.height), 0, 0);
        m_centerPixTex.Apply();

        return m_centerPixTex.GetPixels32();
    }
}
```

I attached it to the main camera where the AR scripts where also attached under. Then i the qr code reader i could simply use the following:

```
public class QRCodeReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    private BarcodeReader barCodeReader;

    FrameCapturer m_pixelCapturer;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        barCodeReader = new BarcodeReader();
        Resolution currentResolution = Screen.currentResolution;
        m_pixelCapturer = cam.GetComponent<FrameCapturer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {

        Resolution currentResolution = Screen.currentResolution;

        try
        {
            Color32[] framebuffer = m_pixelCapturer.m_lastCapturedColors;
            if (framebuffer.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            var data = barCodeReader.Decode(framebuffer, currentResolution.width, currentResolution.height);
            if (data != null)
            {
                // QRCode detected.
                Debug.Log(data);
                Debug.Log("QR: " + data.Text);

                //OnQrCodeRead(new QrCodeReadEventArgs() { text = data.Text });
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error reading QR");
            Debug.LogError(e.Message);
        }

        // skip 1 frame each time 
        // solves GetPixels() blocks for ReadPixels() to complete
        // https://medium.com/google-developers/real-time-image-capture-in-unity-458de1364a4c
        m_pixelCapturer.m_shouldCaptureOnNextFrame = true;

    }
}
```

original source where i adapted this answer to: https://github.com/realityenhanced/ARKitExperiments/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/CaptureCenterPixel.cs

Comment: This works but beware this reads the current screen, so includes also any visible 3D objects

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with both ZXing and ARkit but never together.

Tried to get something working to at least give you a hint on what could be possible.

As a child of your ARCameraManager, add another (additionally to your main AR camera) camera with an ARVideo script attached to it (remove things like audio Listener, Flare layer and guiLayer) Also add the following script, which is just there to retrieve the renderTexture:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class WebcamFetcher : MonoBehaviour
{
private RenderTexture _vertical;
private RenderTexture _horizontal;
private Camera _camera;

// Update is called once per frame
public RenderTexture RenderTexture
{
    get
    {
        var orientation = Screen.orientation;
        if (orientation == ScreenOrientation.Landscape || orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft || orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight)
        {
            return _horizontal;
        }
        else
        {
            return _vertical;
        }
    }
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    _camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
    _horizontal = new RenderTexture(Screen.width, Screen.height, 24);
    _vertical = new RenderTexture(Screen.height, Screen.width, 24);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    var orientation = Screen.orientation;
    if (orientation == ScreenOrientation.Landscape || orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft || orientation == ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight)
    {
        _camera.targetTexture = _horizontal;
    }
    else
    {
        _camera.targetTexture = _vertical;
    }
}
```

}

Then use a script such as:

```
private string DecodeQR(Color32[] pixels, int width, int height)
{
    try
    {
        IBarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();

        // decode the current frame
        var result = barcodeReader.Decode(pixels, width, height);

        if (result != null)
        {
            return result.Text;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Debug.LogError(ex.Message); }
    return null;
}

[SerializeField] Text QrDisplay; // A text field to display detected QRs to

public void OnQrDetect() // a callback for a UI button
{
    var texture = new Texture2D(_webcamFetcher.RenderTexture.width, _webcamFetcher.RenderTexture.height);
    RenderTexture.active = _webcamFetcher.RenderTexture;
    texture.ReadPixels(new Rect(Vector2.zero, new Vector2(_webcamFetcher.RenderTexture.width, _webcamFetcher.RenderTexture.height)), 0, 0);

    var qrText = DecodeQR(texture.GetPixels32(), _webcamFetcher.RenderTexture.width, _webcamFetcher.RenderTexture.height);
    if (qrText != null)
    {
        QrDisplay.text = qrText;
    }
}
```

Worked for me. The texture retrieval might not be the most efficient one.
BUT it works -> it IS possible.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i've also added an answer in which i explained for which solution i went.

Comment: is the question answered now? or still open?